# How to change DataTable's column width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a DataTable in my Flutter app. The problem is that when data is filled, the width of the columns is set automatically, and it too large. How can I manually set the column width? I tried to change the width parameters in the "Widget build", but  it change the width of the whole table, but not a desired column.

Comment: Every column in a DataTable is a widget, therefore you could wrap your column with Container and set the width that way.

Comment: I can wrap DataTable in Widget build method, but I cant wrap desired columns in DataTable method.

Comment: Check my answer bellow

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@Smith, you mean you can't do this ? if you could share some code ...

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DataTable(
        columns: [DataColumn(label: Text('label'))],
        rows: [
          DataRow(cells: [DataCell(
            Container(
              width: 200, //SET width
              child: Text('text')))
              ])
        ]
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I add some code, In wiget build I have only DataTable child:_databody(). Table filled in method _databody()

Comment: Okay, I find my mistake, I forgot to add "child" to text.

Answer (score 30):

Add `columnSpacing` property to DataTable. By default it is set to 56.0.

```
 columnSpacing: 30.0
```

Comment: columnSpacing sets the space between columns, it doesn’t change the width of columns. In his case he’s asking about making columns wider/narrower - while columnSpacing will technically do this, you’re not actually changing column width

Answer (score 11):

Use `columnSpacing` in the DataTable. When set to 0, it takes the length of text content.

```
columnSpacing: 0,
```

Comment: I tried adding this, and co-pilot added the following suggestion "// this doesn't seem to work" - co-pilot was correct.

Answer (score 11):

Better than using `Container` as per the accepted answer, use `ConstrainedBox` so that the cell size will only increase if the contents is equal to or exceeds the constrained width.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Card(
          child: DataTable(columns: [
            DataColumn(
                label: Text(
              'short text column'.toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
            DataColumn(
                label: Text(
              'long text column'.toUpperCase(),
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
          ], rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text('short text')),
              DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250), //SET max width
                  child: Text('very long text blah blah blah blah blah blah',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
            ]),
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text('short text')),
              DataCell(ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250), //SET max width
                  child: Text('very long text blah blah blah blah blah blah',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
            ])
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

View [Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/729f722e41f4bd36ef94c6ff529e5820)

[image: example Flutter data table constrained column width]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Reginaldo Costa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3863983/reginaldo-costa)'s answer, I added LayoutBuilder to get the constraints and use it with SizedBox to make the width's dynamic based on the width constraints.

Will probably useful in developing Flutter web. Here I set a column to have 90% width and the other to have the other 10%.

```
return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
  LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
    return PaginatedDataTable(
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      source: dataSource,
      showFirstLastButtons: true,
      columnSpacing: 50,
      horizontalMargin: 0,
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
            label: SizedBox(
                // 130 is the amount of space consumed by horizontal Paddings and Margins
                width: (constraints.maxWidth - 130) * 0.9,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                  child: Text('Username'),
                ))),
        DataColumn(
            label: SizedBox(
                width: (constraints.maxWidth - 130) * 0.1,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 8, 8, 8),
                  child: Text('Actions'),
                )))
      ],
    );
  })
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to have the `DataTable` fill the parent width. I did this with a `ConstrainedBox` using `minWidth`.

```dart
ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
    child: DataTable(...)
);
```