# Why does a RichText Widget appear after my Text in DataColumns

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a DataTable set up where I do not want horizontal resizeing based on the input. Thus, I wrap the label of my DataColumns and the content of my DataCells in SizedBox widgets. (similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658874/how-to-change-datatables-column-width-in-flutter))

But when I want to size all columns based on a percentage of the DataTables width (obtained via LayoutBuilder), the width does not add up.

I have set horizontalMargin and columnSpacing of the DataTable to 0 and none of my Widgets have padding at the moment.

When I enter the debug paint method, I can see the offending Widget - it is RichText.
[Screenshot of Debug Painter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs2iT.jpg)

On further inspection, I can see that all my Text Widget are displayed as RichText in the DataTable, although I have set them normally:

```
DataColumn(
  label: SizedBox(
    width: fullWidth * 0.4, 
    child: Text('EinsehrlangerStringmitOverflow'),
  ),
)
```

Now my question is: Why do the Text Widgets get displayed as RichText. And more important: How do I get rid of the small quadratic RichText displayed on the Debug Painter screenshot, which is screwing up my layout?

[Another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4tvc.png) from the Widget Inspector, where the Row has 18 additional width compared to the SizedBox (with the Text in it)

**UPDATE:**

The offending Widget was the sorting Button, which gets displayed when passing a function to the `onSort` property of DataColumn. 
Problem was: I passed an empty anonymous function as a placeholder for later, so the place was taken reserved. But because I did not set `sortColumnIndex`, no Arrow was displayed it was not clear to me which Widget takes up the space.

[here is a screenshot to better understand what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKgx7.png)

Comment: Behind the hood the `Text` widget uses `RichText`. You could see the Text widget's code by pressing Ctrl + Left click on Text